# Umbraco 6 - GET /bundles/bundlename 404

Tags: asp.net, azure, msbuild, umbraco

I'm not IIS administrator, not Umbraco user, and not .NET developer, but.

We have an Umbraco application, migrated from another agency to ours. It works on Azure, WebApp.

The problem is: developers team added new locale - but we can't make it work in our environment (but it works locally on developer's workstation). Also - all old locales - works fine (FR in the example below).

We have locale bundle added to the `./App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`:

```
...
var fr_fr = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/script_fr_fr");
var pl_pl = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/script_pl_pl");
...
SetCommonIncludes(pl_pl);
pl_pl.Include(
     "~/client/scripts/ui/dialog/AgeGateDialog_pl_pl.js"
);
...
bundles.Add(fr_fr);
bundles.Add(pl_pl);
bundles.Add(standAloneiFramePage);
...
```

But after application build (with `msbuild`) and deployed (with `msdeploy`) - the *fr_fr* chapter works, while *pl_pl* - gives 404 error:

```
> Request
> URL:http://applicationstaging2.azurewebsites.net/bundles/script_pl_pl
> Request Method:GET Status Code:404 Not Found
```

We have `umbracoReservedPaths` in our `web.config` file with:

```
...
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/api,~/Content,~/Controllers,~/Views,~/Areas,~/radio,~/bundles,~/bundles/" />
...
```

As I understood from googled links - the "bundle" is a memory-based object, created by .NET (since 4.5) application after `GET` request accepted. Then application "generates" this object, which includes some JS/CSS/etc data, put it into memory and must return by path `~/bundles/scriptname`. I.e. - it's not a filesystem object, thus - I can't check its file on the server directly (and can't find it in memory, as this is not normal Linux box with all GNU's utilities).

I'm confused - where to start investigation nad how to solve this. Or at least - how to debug it (Azure's "Application" and "Web server" logs - absolutely useless stuff).

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was due to the dll-files in the `Bin` directory wasn't updated during a build.

Our `build.bat` script was:

```
...
echo [%ME%] Running NuGet restore

%NUGET% restore %SOLUTION%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%

echo [%ME%] Running MSBuild

%MSBUILD% %SOLUTION%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
...
```

`/t:Clean,Build` added to the end of the `%MSBUILD% %SOLUTION%` line fixed problem:

```
...
%MSBUILD% %SOLUTION% /t:Clean,Build
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
...
```

Second updated I made - in the `deploy.bat` script, added `-verb:delete`:

```
...
echo [%ME%] Cleaning up application
%MSDEPLOY% -enableRule:AppOffline -verb:delete -dest:contentPath='%CONTENTPATH%',ComputerName="%COMPUTERNAME%/msdeploy.axd?site=%SITE%",UserName='%USERNAME%',Password='%PASSWORD%',AuthType="Basic"
...
```

Before exact deployment:

```
...
echo [%ME%] Deploying new application
%MSDEPLOY% -enableRule:AppOffline -verb:sync -source:contentPath="%cd%\server\JaegermeisterPlatform_Soln\%SITENAME%" -dest:contentPath='%CONTENTPATH%',ComputerName="%COMPUTERNAME%/msdeploy.axd?site=%SITE%",UserName='%USERNAME%',Password='%PASSWORD%',AuthType="Basic" -setParamFile=%PROPERTYFILE%
...
```